# How to fix "the best overloaded method match for Generic.List<T>.AddRange(Generic.IEnumerable<T>) has some Invalid arguments."?

Tags: c#, linq, generic-list, generic-collections

Above error occour when I addrange Generic.IEnumerable into Generic.List
such as tblOriginalModelInputall.AddRange(xxdata)

DataTable dtTcikerStatusUpdateInTemp2 = objUOW.GetData();

```
            var TcikerStatusUpdateInTemp2 = dtTcikerStatusUpdateInTemp2.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<string>("Ticker").Equals(tickerName)
                && x.Field<string>("Earnings").Equals(earningsToCompare)
                && (((String.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Field<string>("Status")) ? "" : x.Field<string>("Status").Trim()).Equals("A") && (x.Field<string>("InProduction") == null || x.Field<string>("InProduction").Equals(false)))
                || ((String.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Field<string>("Status")) ? "" : x.Field<string>("Status").Trim()).Equals("R")
                && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Field<string>("Comment"))))
                && !x.Field<string>("Client").ToLower().Trim().Equals("cascade"))
                .ToList();               

            if (TcikerStatusUpdateInTemp2.Any())
            {
                var distinctBroker = TcikerStatusUpdateInTemp2.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.Field<string>("ModelFile").Split('_')[0].Trim()).Distinct().ToList();

                if (distinctBroker.Any())
                {
                    RdssDataPram.TblOriginalModelInput objjj = new RdssDataPram.TblOriginalModelInput();
                    List<RdssDataPram.TblOriginalModelInput> tblOriginalModelInputall = new List<RdssDataPram.TblOriginalModelInput>();

                    foreach (var data in distinctBroker)
                    {
                        var xxdata = TcikerStatusUpdateInTemp2.Where(x => x.Field<string>("ModelFile").Contains(data.ToString().Trim() + "_")).OrderByDescending(y => y.Field<int>("ID")).ToList();

                        if (xxdata != null)
                        {
                            tblOriginalModelInputall.AddRange(xxdata); // **error showing here**
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: This question needs more work, its unclear what you are asking, or what the problem is

Comment: one more use of `var` which masks the underlying error... please declare `var TcikerStatusUpdateInTemp2` with the full type then we can see the error

Comment: The Problem Showing:...The best overloaded method match for 
'System.Collections.Generic.List<DALX.Entity.RdssDataPram.TblOriginalModelInput>
.AddRange(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<DALX.Entity.RdssDataPram.TblOriginalModelInput>)'.......TcikerStatusUpdateInTemp2 is a Variable, tblOriginalModelInputall a list Generic.List, xxdata is a Generic.IEnumerable...I am trying to use AddRange on tblOriginalModelInputall  with xxdata....Error showing tblOriginalModelInputall.AddRange(xxdata)  that line.

Comment: ".TcikerStatusUpdateInTemp2 is a Variable" yes we can see that. It's like saying : the shadow is thrown by an animal, and we asked you what **kind of** animal? cat? horse? whale? in other words what is the type of the elements in `xxdata` ? or in `TcikerStatusUpdateInTemp2` ? `IEnumerable<????>` ?

Comment: List<DataRow> TcikerStatusUpdateInTemp2

Comment: Then you need an extra select statement after the order by where you extract the data from the data row and create a new tbloriginalmodelinput

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to use AddRange on `tblOriginalModelInputall` which is `List<RdssDataPram.TblOriginalModelInput>` and your collection `xxdata` which you want to add at the end is not compatible type.
It is not quite clear which types are you using here, but I assume they are not matching.

Comment: Yes...!!  Any solution?

Comment: How to help you if you don't provide more details about the types, classes and variables you use.
Are tblOriginalModelInputall and xxdata related in any way that you could apply Select statement?